# How do I sort an array of hashes by a value in the hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

This Ruby code is not behaving as I would expect:

```
# create an array of hashes
sort_me = []
sort_me.push({"value"=>1, "name"=>"a"})
sort_me.push({"value"=>3, "name"=>"c"})
sort_me.push({"value"=>2, "name"=>"b"})

# sort
sort_me.sort_by { |k| k["value"]}

# same order as above!
puts sort_me
```

I'm looking to sort the array of hashes by the key "value", but they are printed unsorted.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Ruby's `sort` doesn't sort in-place. (Do you have a Python background, perhaps?)

Ruby has `sort!` for in-place sorting, but there's no in-place variant for `sort_by` in Ruby 1.8. In practice, you can do:

```
sorted = sort_me.sort_by { |k| k["value"] }
puts sorted
```

As of Ruby 1.9+, `.sort_by!` is available for in-place sorting:

```
sort_me.sort_by! { |k| k["value"]}
```

Comment: Actually, `Array#sort_by!` is new in Ruby 1.9.2. Available today to all Ruby version by requiring my `backports` gem too :-)

Comment: Hi, is there a way to sort in descending order too? I figure I might want to go `3,2,1`...

Comment: You can't do that with `sort_by`, but use `sort` or `sort!` and simply flip the operands: `a.sort! {|x,y| y <=> x }` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort)

Comment: Or: `puts sorted = sort_me.sort_by{ |k,v| v }`

Comment: @tekknolagi: Just append `.reverse`.

Comment: @Shtééf It is doable via both methods.

Comment: good source of information. Thanks, your answer really help me

Comment: For reverse you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362351/1770571

Answer (score 21):

As per @shteef but implemented with the `sort!` variant as suggested:

```
sort_me.sort! { |x, y| x["value"] <=> y["value"] }
```

Answer (score 8):

Although Ruby doesn't have a `sort_by` in-place variant, you can do:

```
sort_me = sort_me.sort_by { |k| k["value"] }
```

---

`Array.sort_by!` was added in 1.9.2

Comment: This "Array.sort_by! was added in 1.9.2" answer worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort_me.sort_by!{ |k| k["value"]}`. This should work.