# Sort an array with hash elements based on a specific key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@cases => [{"name"=>"25 Cases per 60 day", "count"=>0},
 {"name"=>"30 Cases for 60 days", "count"=>8},
 {"name"=>"10 Cases per 60 days", "count"=>5}]
```

If I have an object which contains the previous results how can I sort by `count` in DESC order?
To get the instance variable `cases` I did

```
ClassName.all.collect{|e| {'name' => e.name, 'count' => e.contracts.count}}
```

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154111/how-do-i-sort-an-array-of-hashes-by-a-value-in-the-hash

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sorted = @cases.sort_by{ |hash| hash['count'] }.reverse
sorted = @cases.sort_by{ |hash| -hash['count'] }
sorted = @cases.sort_by{ |hash| -(hash['count'] || 0) }
```

The first is the simplest.

The second is what I would do.

The third is what you can do if some of the hashes are missing a 'count' value.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Gotta love this community.