# Sort array of hash by key in descending order in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my input hash:

```
h = [
  {user_id: 1, bookings_nd: 3}, 
  {user_id: 2, bookings_nd: 10}, 
  {user_id: 3, bookings_nd: 2}
]
```

I need the result to be sorted in descending order of 'bookings_nd' rather than 'user_id'. I want it to look like this:

```
h = [
  {user_id: 2, bookings_nd: 10}, 
  {user_id: 1, bookings_nd: 3},
  {user_id: 3, bookings_nd: 2}
]
```

How to do it?

Comment: probably best not to call your array `h` since this is usually reserved for hashes.

Comment: We'd like to see your effort toward solving the problem. Without that it looks like you want us to write your code. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do

```
h.sort_by! { |k| -k[:bookings_nd] }
```

or

```
h.sort_by! { |k| k[:bookings_nd] }.reverse!
```

Also i guess this question is duplicate for [Sorting an array in descending order in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642182/sorting-an-array-in-descending-order-in-ruby)